# scroll bar issue with postion fixed

Tags: html, css

The following HTML code is working fine but i am not able to scroll the page, the scroll bar appearing is not been active. Position fixed is needed here to divide the page, so please help me to sort out the issue.

```
 <html lang="en">
<head>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <style>

body
{ 
margin: 0%;
padding: 0%;
}
.container 
{ 


   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   }
#left
{
float: left;
 position: fixed;
     top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;


 }
 #right
{
 position: fixed;

     top: 0%;
    right: 0%;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #59595c; 


 }

 #centrd {

  padding-top: 40%;


}
#centd {

  padding-top: 40%;


}    

.pos_fixed {
    position: fixed;
    top: 3.5%;
    right: 2.5%;
   display: inline-block;
}  




</style>

</head>



    <body>

<div class="container">
<div class="row" >
<div class="col-md-6" style="padding-top:500px;">
<div id="left" align="center">
<div id="centd">
        <img src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/ramc-Untitled-1.png" alt="Smiley face" width="150" height="150">
        </div>


<a href="http://localhost/wordpress/album-categories/wedding/"><img src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Studio-A-travel1.png" alt="list item 1" width="150" / ></a>
<a href="http://localhost/wordpress/album-categories/wedding/"><img src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Knowledge-icon2.png" alt="list item 2" width="150" /></a>

 </div>
 </div>









<div class="col-md-6"  style="padding-top:500px;">
<div id="right" align="center">
       <div id="centrd">
        <img src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/studioa-a1.png" alt="Smiley face" width="150" height="150">
         </div>
        <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/album-categories/wedding/"><IMG src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Studio-A-WED.png" alt="list item 1" width="150" /></a>
      <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/album-categories/wedding/"><IMG src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Studio-A-Cam.png" alt="list item 2" width="150" /></a>


</div>
</div>

 <div class="pos_fixed">
        <a href="http://www.amarramesh.com/contact/"><img src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/get-in-touch.png" alt="Smiley face" width="100" height="100">
        </div>
</div>


</div>
 </div>





</body>
```

Comment: can you show your html-code too?

Comment: what does #right and #left represent ?

Comment: Where you gave the css style name? #left #right represents what?

Comment: this is the html code

Answer (score 0):

{position: fixed;} won't scroll: you are blocking the object (supposedly a div) to a specific part of the window. It will stay there.

Comment: if i am removing postion:fixed then the objects are in random position. please help me.

Comment: Here I am. A question. I have your page on my webserver: you need the page to be divided in two parts and… both parts need to scroll vertically?